Is it possible to consume Kafka or other publish-subscribe topic by Next.js server side (server actions, server components) to update its front end?
There are guides/how-to's on how to publish something from Next.js to Kafka available on the Internet. 
I think it should mean that it is also possible to publish to other message brokers as well.
Yet I am interested to know if it is possible to subscribe or consume by Next.js backend (server actions, maybe server components) to Kafka or other publish-subscribe topic and modify state of Next.js frontend accordingly.
My web search didn't gave me a thing.
There may be some not known to me limitations of Next.js server-side part not allowing such integrations.
If there are I would like to know of them.
P.S. My uneducated guess is that it may be possible to use kafka-consumer-api which is yet to be verified. However, in such a case I do not understand how a server action executed on common Next.js backend can update certain frontends affected by an event consumed.

You could use websockets, server-sent-events (SSE), or polling some other API endpoint that the consumer would update (e.g endpoint that queries a database)
